# Finding string position with for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, strpos

For a school project I need to find the position of the string "AAAAAA" in a long string. I need to use a `for` loop. So far I came up with the following code:

```
<?php
  $string1 = "TATAGTTTCCTCTCTATAT";

  $string2 = str_repeat("AAAGCCTCAAATCTCTCTAGTAAAAAAGCCTCAAATCTCTCTAGTAAA", 6);
  $count = strlen($string1.=$string2);

  for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $string_to_find = $count{$i};
    print(strpos($string_to_find, 'AAAAAA'));
  }
?>
```

I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: declare $string_to_find=""; before the for loop and inside for loop use $string_to_find.=$string1{$i}; instead of $string_to_find=$count{$i}; if you are allowed to use strpos() at least once I don't see any necessity of the for loop by the way.

AND SO is not to do your homework.

Comment: `$string_to_find = $count{$i};` or `$string_to_find = $string1{$i};` ??

Comment: i doubt you are allowed to user strpos, since the would do all the work for you and a for loop would be needless. We won´t make your homework for you here. Which is btw. not really possible anyway because we don´t know what to use which is exactly the point where you could realize this is the worng place since a solution where you musn´t use every available ressource doesn´t forfit anyone other than yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using strpos(), you dont required to use for loop. you can get the results without that.

```
<?php
$string1 = "TATAGTTTCCTCTCTATAT";
$string_to_find="";
$string2 = str_repeat("AAAGCCTCAAATCTCTCTAGTAAAAAAGCCTCAAATCTCTCTAGTAAA", 6);
$count = strlen($string1.=$string2);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
$string_to_find.=$string1{$i};
print(strpos($string_to_find, 'AAAAAA'));
 }
?>
```

here is the code you can try.

Answer (score 0):

I think doing it with a `for`/`foreach` loop is really bad,
anyway, here is your code, changed your code a little, hope it works

```
<?php
  $string1  = "TATAGTTTCCTCTCTATAT";
  $string2  = str_repeat( "AAAGCCTCAAATCTCTCTAGTAAAAAAGCCTCAAATCTCTCTAGTAAA", 6 );

  $count  = strlen( $string1 .= $string2 );
  $temp   = null;

  foreach( str_split( $string1 ) as $char ) {
    $temp .=  $char;
    if ( ( $pos = strpos( $temp, "AAAAAA" ) ) !== false ) {
      print( $pos." " );
      $temp = null;
    }
  }
?>
```